# How to update matrix parameters in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

In Angular2, is there a way to update a matrix parameter, but navigate to the same component? Basically would like to transition easily from a url that looks like:

`/search;term=paris;pageSize=24;currentPage=1;someFilter=value;`

to the same thing, but with currentPage updated upon pagination:

`/search;term=paris;pageSize=24;currentPage=2;someFilter=value;`

using `router.navigate` hasn't appeared to be the best option, since I'd have to write plenty of my own logic to re-construct the url for `navigate`'s use (re-constructing something that already exists).

For kicks and giggles, I did try

`this._router.navigate([this._router.url, {currentPage: this.pagination.currentPage}]);`

but (as you might expect), the router is dumb to the fact that there are matrix parameters on the current url, so the result is not pretty.

EDIT: Should also mention that there may be any number of additional key/value pairs of matrix parameters, so hard-coding any route is out of the question

EDIT: I've since tried to use `preserveQueryParams: true` like:

`this._router.navigate(["..", {currentPage: this.pagination.currentPage}], {preserveQueryParams: true});`

in order to get to an easily usable/transferable solution, but that did not keep the matrix params on the route.

UPDATE: I've since implemented my own logic to get the required behavior, so here's a code snippet for the solution:

```
  let currentParamsArr: Params = this.route.snapshot.params;
  let currentParamsObj: any = { };
  for (let param in currentParamsArr) {
    currentParamsObj[param] = currentParamsArr[param];
  }
  currentParamsObj.currentPage = +pageNum; //typecasting shortcut

  this._router.navigate([currentParamsObj], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

This code loops through the parameters (as they stand in the snapshot), and creates an object out of them, then adds/edits the parameter that I desire to update, then navigates to the "new" route

But, this is not pretty, as I'll essentially have this same logic in many places of the program or have to make a modification to Router or provide some other generic method.

Comment: Perhaps `this._router.navigate([this._router.url, {currentPage: this.pagination.currentPage}], {preserveQueryParams: true});`

Comment: sounds like the right path! Just gave it a shot, and no dice. I think the issue has something to do with this._router.url being a string (it still encoded the semicolons). Is there a more complex object that the navigate method could be used with, which would still contain the query params explicitly?

Comment: This gets me _almost_ where I want: `this._router.navigate(["..", {currentPage: this.pagination.currentPage}]);`, except that it tosses the other query parameters. Also tried adding `{preserveQueryParams: true}` here and it didn't alter behavior

Comment: I guess you need to build a new urlTree using `this._router.createUrlTree()` where you pass the parts that build the route by getting them from `ActivatedRoute` or `this._router..routerState` and traverse the route tree to get all parts. I don't know of an easier way.

Comment: Ah, something I forgot to mention (and perhaps why `preserveQueryParams` didn't work: I'm using matrix parameters and not query parameters in this instance

Comment: `preserveQueryParams` shozld work for matrix params as well. The difference is that query params are query params added to the root segment, while matrix params are query params added to child route segment.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you were right about making a urlTree. I think it's probably the cleanest approach. I've posted the implementation in an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach that ended up working well for me is this:

```
let route: ActivatedRoute;
const newUrl = router.createUrlTree([
  merge({'a': 123}, route.snapshot.params)
], {relativeTo: route});
```

By using merge, you can add, update and subtract url parameters and then use `router.navigateByUrl(newUrl)` in order to execute.

```
add: merge({newParam: 111}, route.snapshot.params)

update: merge({param: 111}, route.snapshot.params)

subtract: merge({param: null}, route.snapshot.params)
```

Hope others find this as useful as I have.

Another example using Object.assign instead of merge:

```
let route = this.route; // The imported ActivatedRoute
let currentParamsObj: Params = Object.assign({}, route.snapshot.params);

let newParam = {};
newParam[key] = value;

let newUrl = this._router.createUrlTree([
        Object.assign(currentParamsObj, newParam)
    ], {relativeTo: this.route });

this._router.navigateByUrl(newUrl);
```

Comment: what is `merge`in this instance? Where did you import it from?

Comment: @Zlatko I ended up using `Object.assign()`

Comment: Just wanted to add that now we can do this: const newUrl = {... route.snapshot.params, ...{'a': 123}}

Comment: @jostyposty well put

Comment: This solution appends the new matrix param to the end of the URL, which is the wrong behavior for my use case

Comment: In my use case, I had parent/child routers, and I was trying to change matrix params in the parent router, so I have to use ```route.parent```. I'll post a separate answer once I get something working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/search;term='+this.term+';pageSize='+this.pageSize+';currentPage='+this.currentPage+';someFilter='+this.someFilter;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Matrix parameters are query parameters added to child segements.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer not sure what you mean by 'query parameters added to child segments'.  I'm currently using matrix params for optional params and a similar approach works fine for me.

Comment: queryParams are added using `NavigationExtras` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the clarification, but I still don't see why this approach would not work since all params would be applied to the /search route in the same format as he originally provided

Comment: I'll have a closer look when I find some time to check if it actually works.

Comment: @JonathanNiu see the answer I just posted. It ends up being really clean, and is easy to make flexible with a function

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a parent and child router, with params on the parent I needed to modify:
`/my-parent;x=1;y=2/my-child`

Working off of @Corbfon's solution, I was able to modify the parent route like this:

```
    // modify the context params in the PARENT route
    const newParam = {'z': '3'};
    const parentParams: Params = Object.assign({ ...this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params }, newParam);

    // note: this approach doesn't preserve params on the child route (but there aren't any in my case)
    const currentChildPath = this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path;

    // notice it's relativeTo the parent route
    const newUrl = this.router.createUrlTree([parentParams, currentChildPath],
      {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent});
    this.router.navigateByUrl(newUrl);
```

Hope this helps someone else.

P.S. Don't forget to use `.snapshot.params` instead of `.params` on the `ActivatedRoute`.