# How to navigate to parent route keeping matrix parameters?

Tags: angular

In an `Angular` application I need to navigate to the parent of a route keeping matrix parameters.

What I want to obtain is navigating from
`http://localhost:4200/a/b;param1=xyz;param2=zxy/c` to `http://localhost:4200/a/b;param1=xyz;param2=zxy`

but when I try to navigate using `router.navigate('..',{relativeTo: this.route.url})` what I get is `http://localhost:4200/a/b`, and route parameters of `b` are lost.

How I can navigate back to `b` from child routes keeping its parameters intact?

Comment: despite the fact that your url at the moment is not well formed, what did you tried so far?

Comment: @alessandro On my question I specified the attempt which I made using router.navigate

Comment: I'm sure, that kind of syntax is valid. It's called matrix URL notation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205929/how-to-update-matrix-parameters-in-angular2